CPU-based LLM for Markdown editor
I'd like to integrate an LLM into my free, open-source, cross-platform desktop Markdown editor. In particular, bundle the LLM into the editor's ancillary podman container (that's used for typesetting). A few areas where the integration may help:

Grammar check
Idea generation
Rephrasing passages
Translating short snippets

Requirements:

Free, open source, MIT/Apache/BSD/etc. license
Local only (no cloud)
GPT-4 quality (or very close)
Fallback to CPU, if GPU unavailable (or CPU-based)
Trained on public works (no copyright material)
Container-friendly (i.e., works with podman)
No Python, if at all possible (not a deal-breaker)

Is there something that could be integrated at this time, or would you suggest waiting until the end of the year to see what shakes out? For example, llama.cpp with Llama2-7B HQQ+?
Thank you!

GPT 4 quality? GPT 4 has 220 billion parameters, that would be a 220 GB file. Do you really want your users to download that for a markdown editor?
